# syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to build tabbed panels where a user can retain at current tab after refresh, updates etc. So, I'm trying to apply this script to my web as a tabbed panel but can't figure out what causes the syntax error. I've been trying to solve the problem for days regarding tabs but can seem to solve it. Btw, I don't use cookies and jquery. I don't use cookies because my friends (my clients) don't use cookies on their terminals. second, I don't use jquery (even though it's better) I prefer php only. please help thank you.

```
<?php 
 $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
    // which tab is active and its associated content
    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
    $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content = $($active[0].hash);
    // Hide the remaining content
    $links.not($active).each(function () {
      $(this.hash).hide();
    });
    // Bind the click event handler
    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
      // Make the old tab inactive.
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $content.hide();
      // Update the variables with the new link and content
      $active = $(this);
      $content = $(this.hash);
      // Make the tab active.
      $active.addClass('active');
      $content.show();
      // Prevent the anchor's default click action
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }); ?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id='tab1'>
    <p>Hi, this is the first tab.</p>
  </div>
  <div id='tab2'>
    <p>This is the 2nd tab.</p>
  </div>
  <div id='tab3'>
    <p>And this is the 3rd tab.</p>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: um, you're running JS inside PHP,. Hence, the error. Those are 2 different animals altogether.

Comment: want to see some magic? replace `<?php` with `<script>` and `?>` with `</script>` ;-)

Comment: This is ***all*** jQuery. *Right Ralph?* @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Si signore Sam* @JayBlanchard hey... what're you doing up at this houir? ah, a late night movie I'll bet. The one about where Wile E. gets the Road Runner?

Comment: *10-4 Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Comment: I find it funny that there's a vote to reopen @JayBlanchard *night Sam*

Comment: It's my vote as this really isn't a PHP parse error dupe @Fred-ii-. It is a complete mismatch of PHP and jQuery which the OP said she didn't want to use. *Totally confused Ralph.*

Comment: Thaaaaank you so much @Fred-ii-. Can you post your comments in the answer section so I can accept your answer. tq soo much..God bless you.

Comment: So which one should I vote?

Comment: Hi Linda. There was a vote to reopen, therefore it should have been reopened as I did now and have provided you with my answer below. Theoretically, the question was off-topic but the vote to reopen by @JayBlanchard would have led to more votes, hence my decision to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Javascript (jQuery to be precise) syntax inside PHP. Hence, the error.

> syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'

- Those are 2 different animals altogether.

Replace `<?php` with `<script>` and `?>` with `</script>` and your code will work.

Comment: Wao u r always genius. .

Comment: @devpro Hey, thanks. *Cheers* and a great and Happy New Year to you!

Comment: Happy new year to.. when ever I see yur name and profie pic I remember pirates of the caribean 5 coming in 2016..

Comment: @devpro that ought to be another great movie. I'll be sure to keep an eye out for it ;-) gotta luv that guy.

Comment: Johny is an another genius in his field.

Comment: @devpro one of my favorite actors. The more obscure, the better it is. ciao for now.

Comment: Nice to talk with u actually I am following yur style how to give a proper answer on SO.. chking some answers related to php. Tc friend

Comment: @devpro right on. Always glad to know that I was able to rub off some of it off another person and to keep Stack the quality site that it should. All the best.

Comment: Just give me one suggestion if an OP ask a question that looks duplicate than what is the better solution mark as duplicate or give the answer ?

Comment: tq @Fred-ii-. I'm  a bit depressed actually, because I was suddenly banned (not sure why )..btw.. tq so much...

Comment: @LindaMay You're welcome. Don't feel bad; I'm sure things will work out. I doubt it's a definite ban, but a timed one. It'll come back. *Cheers*